# How to show that f(x) = x exists for a bounded ordered set and f is an increasing function?

Tags: analysis

Here is the question in full: Let X be an ordered set such that every subset S ⊆ X has both a supremum and an infimum. Suppose that f : X →X is an increasing function, i.e.
∀x, y ∈X if x ≤y ⇒ f (x) ≤f (y).

Show that there exists an x ∈X such that f (x) = x.

I feel like I am on the cusp of getting this. My logic is, since every subset S of X has a supremum and infimum, X itself must be bounded above and below. Then, I say that suppose f(x) > x for all x. What can we say about the value of f(x) at the supremum? With this in mind, f(x) would "exceed" the bound we set for X. Similar logic for f(x) < x for all x. This leaves only that f(x) is not less than x for all x, and f(x) is not more than x for all x. Then I would go from there. The only problem is, I don't think my logic would apply to an open interval, say R (0,1). Am I on the right track in terms of logic or should I switch up my approach?

Comment: By [Knaster–Tarski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem), the set of fixed point of $f$ is itself a [complete lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice) hence nonempty. I doubt the existence of a simpler proof of this nonemptiness.

Comment: The statement isn't true for the open interval $(0,1)$, e.g., the function $f(x)=x^2$ is increasing, but $x^2=x$ has no solution in the open interval.